# Freeing memory of 2D arrays in C

Tags: c, arrays, memory, free

I'd like to know what's the difference between these two functions, if there is any.

```
void dealloc (int**arr, int n)
{
    int i;
    for (i=0; i<n;i++)
        free((*arr)[i]);
    free(*arr);
    *arr=NULL;
}
```

And

```
void deallocpurple (int**arr, int n)
{
    int i;
    for (i=0; i<n;i++)
        free(arr[i]);
    free(arr);
    *arr = NULL;
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: And where are the 2D arrays?

Comment: Well, the second one is guaranteed to be wrong, since you're dereferencing a pointer to freed memory.

Comment: BTW, the most obvious difference is that the first one does not compile.

Comment: The first one is trying to access the actual values in the array and free them, which would totally be bad.

Comment: Where did you get this code?

Answer (score 1):

The first one should be:

```
void dealloc (int**arr, int n)
{
    int i;
    for (i=0; i<n;i++)
        free(*(arr+i));
    free(arr);
    arr=NULL;   // This needs to be fixed in both functions but is not passed back and so, is redundant.
}
```

Now, the two functions are equivalent.

Comment: It did, just fixed it.

Comment: +1 as fixed.

A multidimensional array is implemented as an array of arrays. To free it, free the contained arrays, then free the containing array.

Note that, due to pointer/array math equivalency, there's actually no requirement that the contained arrays be the same length. What's actually stored in the containing array is a pointer to the start of the contained array. Knowing this is sometimes useful.

Comment: What is the difference between free(*(arr+i)) and free((*arr)[i])) ?

Comment: arr[i] and *(arr+1) are equivalent.  (*arr)[i] will be equivalent to *(*arr+i).  The latter will be arr[i][0].

Comment: I am confused about whether I should use the adress or the value when freeing memory. Also, is the first function I wrote down wrong ? It seems to be working

Comment: @pHeoz: You must use the address when freeing memory (after all, the memory even might not contain defined values). The function `dealloc()` you wrote is quite wrong; if it seems to you to be working, you didn't look close enough (you could print out what it tries to `free()`).